# Дни рождения, или как заставить не смотреть на год

Tags: дата, php, mysql

Есть таблица на mysql, в которую занесены дни рождения сотрудников. Надо раз в день смотреть таблицу и искать дни рождения, при этом не надо обращать внимания на год. То бишь, сегодня 11.04.2012 и в базе есть Пупкин с днем рождения 11.04.1990. Надо бы найти этого Пупкина и настукать по голове...  Поля с датами типа "DATETIME".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Substring( `birthday` , 6, 5 ) = '04-11'
```

Или даже так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `birthday` , '%m-%d' ) = '04-11'
```

Answer (score 5):

Поиск всех у кого день рождения 12-го числа в 10-м месяце:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (DAY(birthday) = 12) AND (MONTH(birthday) = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

запрос с лайком можно

```
WHERE birth LIKE '11.04.%'
```

Comment: оу, както не подумал, щас затестю)

Comment: есть контакт только надо писать не '11.04.%' а '%04-11 %'

Answer (score 0):

Искал как выбрать именинников из БД за +-3 дня относительно сегодня, ничего толкового не нашел, поэтому предлагаю свой вариант, вдруг кому-то пригодится:

```
select
    round(timestampdiff(day, date(birth_date), date(now())) / 365) as age,
    date_add(date(birth_date), interval round(timestampdiff(day, date(birth_date), date(now())) / 365) year) as new_birth,
    timestampdiff(day, date(now()), date_add(date(birth_date), interval round(timestampdiff(day, date(birth_date), date(now())) / 365) year)) as days_left,
    u.*
from
    users as u
    having days_left >= -3 and days_left <= 3
    order by days_left
```