# Выбрать ближайшие даты из текущего года

Tags: mysql

Допустим есть таблица с разными датами (день рождения, день ВДВ, год без наркотиков, вернуть долг пете). Некоторые повторяются каждый год, некоторые повторяются один раз. Вся колонка с датами в формате DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Какой запрос выведет ближайшие даты без учета года.

Comment: что такое "ближайшие даты"?

Comment: Что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99516/%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4 ? или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776222/194569

Comment: Имеется ввиду дни рождения (допустим 18.07.1993, 15.07.1991) но в базе так-же могут храниться значение которые не повторяются каждый год, а используются один раз

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать выборку из базы данных по месяцу и дате в диапозоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776222/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)